# Where to find macOs CrashReporterPrefs?

Tags: xcode8, crash-reports

I am looking for the CrashReporterPrefs application to enable crash report for command line application. I used to be installed with Xcode but it seems to not be part of the XCode package anymore.

Anyone does know if there is a new way to do that or if it has been simply removed by Apple?

Answer (score 1):

CrashReporterPrefs is part of the Additional Tools for Xcode package. Go to Apple's [developer downloads page](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/), filter for "additional", download the appropriate Additional Tools disk image. CrashReporterPrefs is within the Utilities folder in that disk image.